# Adding more than one independent images using a single image view

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

I am trying to pick images from the gallery in my  android application and I want to place them above each other,
but the problem is that I want to use only a single image view.
Does anyone know the code for that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Create it dynamically

Comment: Hey Nitesh what do you mean by dynamically?

Comment: You may try using gridview or recyclerview

Comment: @Nitesh Recyclerview is for listing items I guess, but how does gridview helps me here?

Comment: @Nitesh I mean by above each other on the Z-axis like in a FrameLayout